# markdown toolbar view hides when press left arrows icon

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, asking-questions, ios-app

When I press left arrows on additional keyboard view hides and paintbrush icon become visible

> [image]

Comment: Pretty sure that's [tag:status-bydesign]. When there are three `<<<`, it collapses. When there's one `<` or `>` it scrolls between buttons

Comment: Oh, yea, you are right, but this is bit unusual for me.

Comment: Does this seem more intuitive? http://i.stack.imgur.com/ysHQ1.png

Comment: I frustrated with paintbrush more that with arrows, so is hard to say what is better

Comment: Oh, so it's more that you wish the icons were always there and never had the paintbrush?

Comment: No just other icon to show tools again

Comment: After sleep I can say what will be better option. When user press left arrows additional tools view moves to left and icon changes to three arrows right '>>>' animation will explain what is going, and I sure no one become frustrated with brush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design.  When you're in landscape, the bar can pretty much take up the whole screen. (It's pretty crowded on a 4S too.)  Tapping that paintbrush icon will get it back.

Comment: How would you feel about changing it to something like this instead? http://i.stack.imgur.com/ysHQ1.png